# My API (aws API service) is not giving the same response when running tests and using postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I have a setup a lambda function (generateOTP) that is integrated with my API gateway the invoke URL is `https://url/dev/generateOTP` . Here is my lambda function

```
import json
import random 


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    phone=event.get("number")
    otp = random.randint(1000, 10000)    
    
    dic = {"phone": phone, "otp": otp}
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(dic)
    }
```

I have configured a test event as follows

```
{
  "number": "+910123456789"
}
```

upon running the test event here is the result

```
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"phone\": \"+910123456789\", \"otp\": 9131}"
}
```

but when I make the same request(POST) through postman i get this as the response

```
{
    "phone": null,
    "otp": 5890
}
```

I tried changing the format of the object being returned, and even tried different variations of accessing variables (event['number'], event.get('number'). I don't know how to approach this issue

Answer (score 0):

`event` format for API gateway is different that what you have in your test. Please check [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway.html#apigateway-example-event) how the `event` is actually structured, and modify your code to use the correct format.